# imported bones locked in rotation

Tags: rigging

I imported a character from Daz, and it has a bunch of bones for the eyelid I need to pose. The problem is, I can't rotate them, even if I unlock the rotation and remove all bone constraints. There's some relation that pose them relative to the eye position but I don't know where this relation is. Where could it be aside from bone constraints?

Comment: hello, could you please share your armature (or just the important part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This is driving me crazy, I exported a base figure in Blender and could unlock the bones in this one by removing the drivers on the rotation values. But the driver menu does NOT appear in the file I need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was a driver script on the rotation values, figured it out.

EDIT: and the value must not be keyframed to remove the driver.